# Simplify Jquery script, dynamic - two select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to simplify this script and make it dynamic.
There can be more than two items in options. I can't imagine what it would look like with ten items.

In this case, the maximum number of items is 2. The sum of the values of both selects must not exceed the max.
E.g. select one = 1, select two = 0 and 1, 2 = disabled

I would need the script to expand, for example, 10 items and more

Everything will be loaded via a loop in PHP for more items (frm-step1-deluxe1, ...) and I would need it to be generated dynamically.

```js
$("#frm-step1-standard1").change(function() {
  var va1 = parseInt($(this).val());
  var va2 = parseInt($("#frm-step1-standard12").val());
  if (va1 == 0) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 1) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 2) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 3) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 4) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 5) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12").val(0);
  } else {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=5]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }

});

$("#frm-step1-standard12").change(function() {
  var va1 = parseInt($(this).val());
  var va2 = parseInt($("#frm-step1-standard1").val());
  if (va1 == 0) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 1) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 2) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 3) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 4) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 == 5) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1").val(0);
  } else {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=3]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=4]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=5]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  option:disabled {
    background: #ccc;
  }
</style>

<select name="standard1" id="frm-step1-standard1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="standard12" id="frm-step1-standard12">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give it some flexibility I would add a variable defining the total value to be allowed in both selects. Then on change retrieve the current value of the select, substract it from the max allowed and disable all options on the second select that would exceed the total.

The lower part of the script is the initialisation of the two selects as I did not want to waste space and was too lazy to manually write the options in the selects :-).

```js
let maxSum = 10;

let lockOptions= function() {
  let $select= $(this);
  let remaining= maxSum - parseInt($select.val());
  let id = $select.prop('id');
  let $otherSelect= $('select:not(#'+id+')');
  let options= $otherSelect[0].options;
  for (let i = 0;i<options.length;i++) {
    options[i].disabled= options[i].value > remaining;
  }
}

let selects= $('select');
if (selects.length > 0) {
  for (let select of selects) {
    let $select= $(select);
    $select.on('change', lockOptions)
    for (let i = 0;i<=10;i++) {
        $select.append($('<option>').val(i).text(i));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1"></select>
<select id="s2"></select>
```

All you will need besides your own PHP logic (or manual addition of option values) is this part:

```js
let maxSum = 10;

let lockOptions= function() {
  let $select= $(this);
  let remaining= maxSum - parseInt($select.val());
  let id = $select.prop('id');
  let $otherSelect= $('select:not(#'+id+')');
  let options= $otherSelect[0].options;
  for (let i = 0;i<options.length;i++) {
    options[i].disabled= options[i].value > remaining;
  }
}

let selects= $('select');
if (selects.length > 0) {
  for (let select of selects) {
    let $select= $(select).on('change', lockOptions);
  }
}
```

Execute this somewhere in a `<script>` tag at the end of your script (after generating the `<select>` boxes via PHP). If there are more dropdowns on the page you will need to use additional filter criteria, e.g. classes (`<select class="connected-select">...</select>`) and then also filter in the JS part (`let selects= $('select.conncected-select');`).

Comment: Amazing. I just need the option not to be generated via jquery. I generate it differently via php or manually.
`let maxSum = 10`, that's what I really needed.
I also substitute ID select dynamically, but I can't customize the script.

Comment: @aha009 yeah, after a while you can't imagine how you once tried to solve things :-). I tried to extract the relevant part and added it to the bottom of my answer, see if that helps.